# How can I host a webapp that is not designed by Nextjs or React but simple html, js, css and flask/python?

Tags: next.js, web-applications, localhost, hosting, vercel

How can I host a web app not designed by Nextjs or React but by simple html, js, CSS and Flask/python? I tried to host it on Vercel using my GitHub repo but file routing is completely off - the app works locally on a computer but not when I deploy it.